# What are the morphisms in the domain of the character space functor for non-unital comm. Banach algebras?

Tags: category-theory, soft-question, operator-algebras

Think of the contravariant functor sending a non-unital commutative Banach algebra to its character space

$$F : \mathcal A^{\text{op}} \to \operatorname{LCHaus}, A \mapsto \hat A; f^{\text{op}} : A \to B \mapsto \cdot \circ f : \hat A \to \hat B $$

What are the "right" morphisms in $\mathcal A$? Characters need to be non-zero. This disqualifies some of the the typical, say, short (i.e. norm-decreasing) algebra morphisms. To ensure that $\tau\circ f$ is always a character we may want to insist that $f$ is surjective. But I'm not sure that's the best choice we have.

Comment: If you write the opposite, it becomes a covariant functor.

Comment: Regardless of the morphisms in $\mathcal{A}$, the space of characters can be zero.

Comment: @QuantumSpace A matter of notation I suppose... 
"Can be zero" - do you mean empty? It would indeed be problem if $\hat B$ is empty, but $\hat A$ isn't.

Comment: I asked a related question a long time ago here which got a lot of great answers: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170984/are-commutative-c-algebras-really-dual-to-locally-compact-hausdorff-spaces

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Oh boy. That's really what I was looking even if I didn't know at all what to expect.

Comment: @StefanPerko Yes I meant empty, sorry (if you require characters to be non-zero, otherwise there is the zero character). Also the related question is somewhat different: if $A$ is a commutative $C^*$-algebra, then $A=C_0(X)$ for some locally compact Hausdorff space and you have lots of characters. For a general commutative Banach algebra, nothing ensures one character even exists.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Ah true, I was not reading it very carefully.